# Can't edit text with media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have the following html for my header.

```
<header id="header">
            <img src="images/logo.png"/>
            <div class="container">

                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="about">About Me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pricing">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="sessions">Sessions</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="signup">Sign Up</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
```

I have the following for my CSS:

```
    img .header-basic{
height:30px;
}


#content {
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top:00px;
}
#logo {
    height: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 75px;
}
#content img{
    float:right;
}


/*Header*/
#header img {
    width: 450px;
    height: auto;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
    #header img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #nav ul {
        text-align: center;
    }

        #nav ul li {
            display: inline;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-left: 15px;
            margin-right: 15px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Verdana';
        }

            #nav ul li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
                font-size: 20px;
                font-family: 'Verdana';
            }
}
    #nav ul {
        text-align: center;
    }

        #nav ul li {
            display: inline;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-right: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Verdana';
        }

            #nav ul li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
                font-size: 20px;
                font-family: 'Verdana';
            }

    /*End Header*/
```

My media query activates for making the image smaller but the text stays the same. I want the margin to be decreased to keep all the navigation on one line. I am coding in Visual Studio and testing in Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just decrease the **margin** and the **font-size** to make them in one line like this :

```css
    img .header-basic{
height:30px;
}


#content {
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top:00px;
}
#logo {
    height: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 75px;
}
#content img{
    float:right;
}


/*Header*/
#header img {
    width: 450px;
    height: auto;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
 #nav ul {
        text-align: center;
    }

        #nav ul li {
            display: inline;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-left: 15px;
            margin-right: 15px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Verdana';
        }

            #nav ul li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
                font-size: 20px;
                font-family: 'Verdana';
            }

@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
    #header img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

   
    #nav ul {
        text-align: center;
    }

        #nav ul li {
            display: inline;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Verdana';
        }

            #nav ul li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-family: 'Verdana';
                
            }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:468px) {
  
  #nav ul li {
            
            margin-left: 1px;
            margin-right: 1px;
      
        }

            #nav ul li a {
                font-size: 10px;
}
}
    /*End Header*/
```

```html
<header id="header">
            <img src="images/logo.png"/>
            <div class="container">

                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="about">About Me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pricing">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="sessions">Sessions</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="signup">Sign Up</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: This does keep them on the same line, but I want them to become smaller when it is a smaller device.

Comment: you can add media for smaller devices the same way.  i will add it to the code snippet.

Comment: I added media for smaller screen < 468  that will make font-size:10px and margin-right:1px , margin-left:!px; you can edit this as you need.